# Solve the linear system in two space?

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces

$(x,y) = (-12,-7) + s(8,-5) $

$(x,y) = (2,-1) + t(3,-2)$

**attempt**

Use elimination:

$8s - 3t = 14$

$-5s + 2t = 6$

$s = \frac{10}{33}$

find point:

$-12 + 8\cdot\frac{10}{33} = -9.575757$
$-7 - 5\cdot\frac{10}{33} = -8.515151$

So it should be $(-9.58, -8.52)$

CORRECT ANSWER:

$(356,-237)$

What am I doing wrong? thanks!

Comment: When you multiplied both sides of the first equation by $2$, and of the second by $3$, you **subtracted** instead of adding.

Comment: Whoops! But wait then my s value is s = 46/3..which is still wrong

Comment: $2(8)+3(-5)=1$, and $2(14)+3(6)=46$, so $s=\frac{46}{1}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas thanks as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method is 100% right, except your substitution for $s$. As you don't show the work, I don't know where you made the mistake. If you can show it in the comments, I can help more.

But If I use what you did, I get
$$x=356 , y=-237 , s=46 , t=118 $$

Here are more details
$$ 8s - 3t = 14 \tag 1$$
$$-5s + 2t = 6 \tag 2$$

Multiply (1) by $2$ and (2) by 3 and add to get
$$s = 46$$
Multiply (1) by $5$ and (2) by 8 and add to get
$$t =118$$

Comment: for my s value i got 46/3 :p

Comment: nevermind, i don't know how to do simple math omg! Thank you!!

Comment: Can you share your calculations to see where your mistake is?

Comment: simple math is always the killer :)

Comment: Expect the unexpected! Thanks again!